# Convert Julia to EXE with help of PyInstaller

Tags: python, julia, pyinstaller, exe, pycall

For a while now, I've been trying to compile a Julia package into an EXE with little success. Recently, I decided to take a look into wrapping it with Python and then transforming it to an EXE. This has worked great except the EXE crashes on startup show the attached error message. Can any of ya'll help me understand what the error is or even if this is the correct path? The error persists with the `--onedir` attribute as well.
[image: CMD Error Message]

Comment: You might want to look into the PackageCompiler.jl which claims to compile into an app (I did not use it). here is a link to the example: https://julialang.github.io/PackageCompiler.jl/dev/apps.html

Comment: I have looked into PackageCompiler, but the executable it generates seems to be linked to the folder paths on my computer. It was unusable on any other system.

Comment: I see, I would open an issue about the problem though. While it might be too late for you it could help others in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

In your command prompt,

```
 pip uninstall typing
```

Then run your pyinstaller command again. It won't crash

Comment: Typing is already uninstalled. Or at least, I have never installed it. Also, the pyinstaller command works fine, the resulting executable is the thing that crashes.

Comment: I know. That's what I also faced about 3weeks ago. What I suggested to you resolved mine

Comment: Hey, you've not even tried what I told you. I never installed typing snd didn't even know there's any module named python there before I did as instructed and my issue was resolved.

Comment: I have tried it, I am saying that when executing your answer, I get the message "WARNING: Skipping typing as it is not installed."